# Get WKWebView content size once loading is completed

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiwebview, contentsize

We have a requirement to disable scrolling of web view and show the complete web view content in a table view cell, and only table view should be scrolling not the web view

Tried the below approach, but it's not giving the correct content size of the web view if we disable scrolling of the WKWebView.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.updateWebView(for: webView)
    }
    func updateWebView(for webView: WKWebView) {
        let scaleFactor: CGFloat = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 1.0 : 0.70
        let scaleJavascript = "var style = document.createElement(\"style\"); document.head.appendChild(style); style.innerHTML = \"html{-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; font-size: 25px; word-wrap: break-word;}\";var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');viewPortTag.id=\"viewport\";viewPortTag.name = \"viewport\";viewPortTag.content = \"width=device-width; user-scalable=0.0; initial-scale=\(scaleFactor); minimum-scale=\(scaleFactor); maximum-scale=\(scaleFactor); shrink-to-fit=no;\";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(scaleJavascript, completionHandler: { [weak self] (_, _) in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                self?.height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
                self?.onUpdate?(nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

Any help or lead is highly appreciated.

Comment: So you are really using UIWebview, aren't you? It's the delegate method for the wkwebview that your code block indicated.

Comment: my bad, its WKWebView

Comment: Why don't you inject the scaleJavascript in the WKUserscript. I doubt if you evaluate it after the webview being finished loading will work.